# How to add rows based on the number of criteria in a column in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have been trying to figure this problem out for a while but I cannot think of an answer. Some context here: I have two worksheets. In sheet one, I have a column that is full of names. In the second sheet, I have an outline that has 10 rows that display the names. However, if in sheet one there are 11 names, the 11th name would not appear in sheet two because there are only 10 rows. What I need to figure out is how to insert a row for the 11th names (or nth depending on how many names are added). Once I add the nth row, I would auto fill the formula down which is the easy part. The part I cannot figure out is how to insert the row.

What I was thinking was inserting a COUNT function that would count the different names and insert the rows that way. But is there a way I could do it so there would not be a random number (the number being the COUNT) in a cell in one of my worksheets?

Comment: This is definitely possible, however od you have any code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding, you want to insert n-10 number of rows with n being total number of rows of names.

Try this

```
Sub test()

Dim startr, endr As Range
Set startr = Range("A7")        'Set this to be the first row of your list of names

If Not startr.Value = "" Then
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        Do Until startr.Offset(i).Value = ""
        i = i + 1
        Loop
    End With
    Set endr = startr.Offset(i - 1)     'endr is now the last row of the names

    totalr = Range(startr, endr).Rows.Count     'totalr is the total number of rows/names
    If totalr > 10 Then
        addr = totalr - 10      'addr is the number of rows you need to add
        MsgBox "You need to insert  " & addr & "  more rows."

        'The following finds the last row of column A and inserts addr number of rows
        Dim lastr As Range
        Set lastr = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
        lastr.Offset(1).EntireRow.Resize(addr).Insert
    Else
    MsgBox "Number of rows/names is  " & totalr & "  which is less than 10, so no rows are being added."
    End If
Else
MsgBox startr.Address(0, 0) & "  is empty."

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: From my understanding, is addr a number? Let us say I have 19 rows, does addr then read 9? So when we get to the end of the code, it says in sheet2, insert addr after lastr? So we now have lastr plus and extra 9 rows?

Comment: @GCC yes to all

Comment: I do not understand how your code is counting the number of names. I forgot to mention that in my list, there is repeating names that refer to the same person. So if a name is repeated, it should count as 1 and not the number of times the name is mentioned in the list.

Comment: Hey, so the code is counting 19 unique values but there are actually 25 values. Is there a reason why it is under counting?

Comment: @GCC  Are there any empty rows between each name in your list? Did you set startr correctly? Did you use "i" for any other calculation?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I did have i labelled as something else. Thanks!